# wamp server not woking after installing svn module to Apache

Tags: svn, wampserver

i Installed wamp server with Apache 2.0.63 and Php 5.2.9 and mysql 5.1.33 versions. my svn servser is [usvn](https://github.com/usvn/usvn). wamp full-fill  requrement of [usvn](https://github.com/usvn/usvn). as its [Wiki](https://github.com/usvn/usvn/wiki/Installation) say to me, i installed all module except "mod_authz_svn.so" and "mod_dav_svn.so". before installing this all module i restarted my Wamp server and have a Good PING to localhost. but after intalling "mod_authz_svn.so " and "mod_dav_svn.so" module i failed to Start my wamp server.

after watching Error - Logs Of APACHE, PHP, MYSQL i got error in Mysql's log. it Say me That **host is null so it take default host as 0.0.0.0, so Failed to start**.

please help me if you seems anything Wrong.

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Do you really want SVN on a WAMP? Why not a dedicated package?

Comment: What do you get when you run `httpd -t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used Old version of Apache while i have "mod_authz_svn.so" and "mod_dav_svn.so" module compiled with newer version of Apache so my Apache service not started successfully. after reading a documentation of subversion i knew this, these both module were compiled with new version of Apache, then i changed Apache service with latest one and Get Success.

Thanks For reading my question.